# Add Followers in Task

Tags: asana

Can I add an array of followers in the creation of the task? There addTag & addProject. The task is written followers read-only.
Thank you, Ruslan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation does say that followers is read-only, but it's not when you are creating a task. So some JSON like this when you are creating a task will let you set the followers:

```
{ "data" : {  "name": "task name", "workspace": 12345, "assignee" : 56123, "followers": [6677, 1234]  } }
```

But you can't (yet) change the followers via the API once it's created.

Comment: Thank you, If you have time to help fill - https://github.com/rushis/asana-api/wiki. This is a wrapper asana api for node.js.